# Toggle SVG with jQuery .html()

Tags: jquery, svg, toggle

i'm trying to to toggle two svg on click:

```
$('.close').html() == '<svg class="btn_back"><use xlink:href="#btn_back"></use></svg>' ? $(this).html('<svg class="btn_i"><use xlink:href="#btn_i"></use></svg>') : $(this).html('<svg class="btn_back"><use xlink:href="#btn_back"></use></svg>');
```

the html is:

```
<div class="back"><svg class="btn_i"><use xlink:href="#btn_i"></use></svg></div>
```

on the first click the content ist replaced and the `btn_back` svg is shown properly. when i click `.close` the second time the svg doesn't change.

is the `.html()` the wrong tool?

thanks for any help!

Comment: Please read [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) and [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/). You should have done it before posting your question. That's what *"Search and research."* mean in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

I'd toggle a class on it. Based on that, I'd switch HTML, which is faster than making a string comparison. Besides, `.html()` does not always return a string, so I think you're much safer like this. Probably not perfect, but a bit better than your approach.

```js
$(document).on('click','.close', function(e){
  var close = $(e.target).closest('.close');
  close.toggleClass('on');
  close.html(close.hasClass('on') ? 
    '<svg class="btn_i"><use xlink:href="#btn_i"></use></svg>', 
    '<svg class="btn_back"><use xlink:href="#btn_back"></use></svg>'
    );
})
```

Comment: thanks andrei!
sorry for the poor search and research but when i used the code with tex instead of the svg it worked. and i'm not that good in jquery.

Comment: There's nothing to be sorry about, @PhilippWilhelmSchäfer. You had the opportunity to learn a few things today so you should be thankful. One of them is to (re)search your questions before asking. Overall, this will make you ask better questions and receive better answers.